# Access website on mobile

Tags: web, mobile

i have developed a php mysql website and now i want to access this website via my mobile.
What are the requirements for achieving this ?

As far as i know, i need to have an internet connection in my mobile...
Whatelse are needed to achieve this ?

Please specify...

Comment: A mobile browser, such as Fennec, Opera, Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Phone should have the capability for data browsing.
2. GPRS / EDGE / 3G / Any Data plan with your carrier.
3. The website should preferably confirm WAP 2.0 ( Mobile Profile )specs ( i.e., use XHTML instead of regular HTML). Though latest phone browsers on the latest smartphones do render some bit of broken HTML.
4. The Website should be formatted for mobile eg taking care of limited screen size. The Website should also be lighter so that it is easier to load up as mobile bandwidth is more expensive.
5. Run you website though this URL - [Mobi Ready](http://mobiready.com/). It will tell you whether you website is formatted correctly for mobile devices. It will also give suggestions on what you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

A browser on your mobile and probably a mobile optimized version of your site to preserve bandwidth as it could cost more money on mobile.